# BeautifulSoup: how to replace content with in span tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
........<p style=" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; text-indent:0px;">textHere

<span style=" font-family:'Noto Sans';">ABC</span></p>

<p style=" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; text-indent:0px;"><span style=" font.......
```

I have a HTML like above. I need to

1. find all the content in 'Noto Sans' font-family (they are always inside span tag)
2. replace them (A as X, B as Y etc…) with out changing rest of the code

what I tried is this, but not working properly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
source_code = """.....<span style=" font-family:'Noto Sans';">ABC</span></p>......""
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "lxml")

for re in soup.findAll('font', 'face' = "Noto Sans"):
    print (re.replace("A", "X"))
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find all `span` tags having `font-family: Noto Sans` inside, then replace the `A` with `X` inside every `span` element that you've found:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


source_code = """.....<span style=" font-family:'Noto Sans';">ABC</span></p>......"""    
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "lxml")

for elm in soup.find_all('span', style=re.compile(r"font-family:'Noto Sans'")):
    elm.string = elm.text.replace("A", "X")

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<span style=" font-family:'Noto Sans';">
 XBC
</span>
```